# Is $\{{\operatorname{sinc}}\big({z}-n\big)\}_{n\in \mathbb Z}$ a Riesz basis for $PW_\pi$?

Tags: functional-analysis

N.K. Bari has proved (see N.K. Bari, "Biorthogonal systems and bases in Hilbert space" Uchen. Zap. Moskov. Gos. Univ. , $148$ : $4$ ($1951$) pp. $69–107$) that a system $\{\phi_n\}$ is a Riesz system if and only if there exists a continuous linear operator $A$, invertible in $L^2$, such that the system of functions $\{A \phi_n\}$ is complete and orthonormal.

Since ${\operatorname{sinc}}\big({z}-n\big)$, $z\in \mathbb C$, is the image of $e^{-inx}$ under the inverse Fourier transform, the collection $\{{\operatorname{sinc}}\big({z}-n\big)\}_{n\in \mathbb Z}$ is an orthonormal basis of $PW_\pi$ (Paley-Wiener space). I wonder: is this system also a Riesz basis for $PW_\pi$? Suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Every orthonormal Basis is a Riesz Basis.

Comment: @PhoemueX. Thank you. Where can I find this fact? Can you recommend some references please?

Comment: This has me really confused. You mention the Fourier transform and say that the sinc function is the inverse image of the exponential but that's really not true (you'd get a Dirac delta). Did you mean to put an ideal window on that?

Comment: Do you know the definitions of Riesz Basis and of an orthonormal basis (including things like Pythagoras theorem and Paraevals formula)? If so, the proof is a straightforward application of the definition of a Riesz Basis.